# A list of values of a column - but only once

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have this for example:
[image: Example]

I want to write an Excel command that will return (at other column for example) only the values (but once), about the example above - the result will be: A, B, C.

Thank you!

Comment: This can be done with Excel pivot table: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576

Comment: Have you tried [**looking for a ready solution**](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+unique+values+in+column+formula)? For example, [**Find Unique Values in a Column in Excel (6 Methods)**](https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-unique-values-in-column/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try (for example):

```
=UNIQUE($A$1:$A1000)
```

If your data is in a Table, this will be even better as it will accommodate changes to how many rows to look at as the table expands.
If you want the result sorted, use:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE($A$1:$A1000))
```

Comment: I got  #NAME?  ..

Comment: @Yoar Check any of [these reasons](https://exceljet.net/formulas/how-to-fix-the-name-error) for a possible #NAME error.

Comment: I think it's because I'm using Excel 2016 :-\

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following formual.

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,SMALL(IF(MATCH($A$2:$A$7,$A$2:$A$7,0)=ROW($A$1:$A$6),ROW($1:$6),4^8),ROW(A1))),"")`

[image]